# Azure AD B2C and subdomains

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

Our application is a SPA app, using hello.js to communicate with Azure AD B2C. We also leverage custom policies and dynamic styling of the Azure AD B2C screens.

Let's assume we have N subdomains (subdomain1.maindomain.com, subdomain2.maindomain.com, … subdomainN.maindomain.com) with N > 20 (which is the max number of redirect URIs in Azure AD B2C)

As of today, when a user navigates to subdomain1.maindomain.com, we redirect him to **maindomain.com?query=subdomain1**

Based on the query parameter, we infer a custom policy and potentially some other parameters that we want to apply to our custom Azure B2C UI in a dynamic fashion (we therefore pass these parameters as query string parameters of the policy URL)

It enables us to have **only 1 redirect URI** setup in Azure AD B2C (maindomain.com/Redirect)

However, the "?query=subdomain1" is removed once the user is logged in. If a user bookmarks a page of the site once he is logged in, he will bookmark a page like : maindomain.com/SomePage. If he goes back to this page later on, we will not be able to infer the right custom policy and style. We could store some information in the localstorage of the user browser but this could be deleted as well.

**Ideally, we would like to keep the URL as subdomain1.maindomain.com all the way (with no query string).**

**Is it at all possible to do that with Azure AD B2C in a secure way ?**

1. I guess it would if we could define wildcards redirect URI in Azure AD B2C such as *.maindomain.com but I understand it is not supported.
2. As we are limited to 20 redirect URIs in Azure AD B2C, we cannot just register all subdomains redirect URIs on the application in Azure AD B2C (we could have an unlimited number of subdomains)
3. Our application is a SPA app, we are using hello.js on the front end. If we keep a common redirect URI, when the redirect occurs, it stores the token info in the storage of the maindomain.com site, hence not accessible from the subdomain.

Comment: I'm very late to the party here, but you could bounce to a top level authentication url (e.g `example.com/auth`), then redirect to a subdomain `tenant1.example.com` (the token will still work). Or, you could change your tenancies to work as part of the url but not part of the domain e.g. `example.com/tenant1`. That way, you would only need `example.com` in your redirect URI's.